# How do I show 3-SAT is decidable?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, turing-machines, satisfiability, decidability

Knowing that we have a Turing machine that can do anything a C program can do, how do I show 3-SAT is decidable?

I know 3-SAT is satisfiable if we can find boolean values for the literals so at least one clause is set to true.

I understand the definition of decidable is basically if we have an algorithm that decides every instance of the problem (3-SAT in this case).

I'm confused on how to combine this knowledge to show 3-SAT is satisfiable.

Comment: You can imagine just enumerating all possibilities for the variables, and determining whether the expression is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense

Comment: Normally, when people talk of 3-SAT, they refer to CNF SAT. Then a satisfying assignment has to satisfy *all* clauses at once.  Still, if there are $n$ variables in your formula, you "only" need to run through $2^n$ cases.  There are much more clever ways to check satisfiability, but the dumb, brute-force approach is enough to prove decidability.

Answer (score 1):

Let be `0 = false`, `1 = true`, `f` the boolean function. The following pseudocode

`s = 0
for x = 0 to 1
    for y = 0 to 1
        for z = 0 to 1
            if f(x,y,z) = 1 then s = 1
        next z
    next y
next x
return s`

returns `0/false` if the formula isn't satisfiable, `1/true` if is satisfiable.